# .val() not returning correct value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that runs on change for a select box:

```
 $('#reg-phone-type').change( function() {
      console.dir($(this));
      console.log("$(this).val():" + $(this).val());
    if( $(this).val == 'work' ) {
      // do one thing
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  });
```

When I print out `console.dir($(this));` I can see that the selected option is set (in my screenshot example) to "work" (the label is proper case, but the actual option value is lower, so I know I'm not dealing with a case issue).

[image]

Here's the HTML from Firebug after the select box was changed (default is "home"):

[image]

```
<select name="regPhoneType" id="reg-phone-type" style="display: none;" value="work">
    <option value="home">Home</option>
    <option value="work" selected="selected">Work</option>
    <option value="cell">Cell</option>
</select>
```

So you can see that the option is correctly selected. Why, then, when in my jquery, just one line later, I call `console.log("$(this).val():" + $(this).val());`, do I get "home" instead of "work"? My understanding was that `.val()` returns the value of the selected option of a select box, so I should be getting "work".

[image]

Comment: Do you by any chance have any other fields with the same id?

Comment: @j08691 actual code is at the top of the question.

Comment: @Juhana - nope, no other fields with the same ID.

Comment: @pjmorse - I meant the HTML.

Comment: @j08691 - the HTML is dynamically generated, so I can't post the actual HTML, only what is rendered. Easiest way in that case is with a Firebug screenshot.

Comment: You could post the generated HTML...

Comment: If the display of the select is set to none, how is the value being changed? Also, it seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LuUNt/

Comment: Not sure why it's such a big deal, since it's just a tiny snipped, but I posted the actual rendered html.

Comment: you are setting selectbox attribute value inline, thats the big deal i think

Comment: Also, someone else posted an answer that actually fixed the problem, but it was deleted while I was in the middle of commenting on it. Don't know who you were, but if you repost it I will accept it. The answer was to use `$('option:selected', this).val()` instead of just `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @j08691 - the value is being set programmatically by another change.

Comment: Part of the problem: $(this).val is not equivalent to $(this).val()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#reg-phone-type option:selected').val();
```

or

```
$('option:selected',this).val();
```

Comment: $(this).val() should returns selected option value too

Comment: Maybe `$(this).val()` should return the selected option, but in this case it doesn't, while the answer code does.

Comment: It's related to having another element change the value while your code above is targeting the change event of the select element which is actually hidden.

Comment: Attribute value is not a valid W3C's attribute for select element, thats your problem i think. Anyway, you should remove it or continuing to find workaround each time classic behaviour dont work, thats up to you

Comment: Yeah, I suspect whatever is changing the value isn't doing it by the book. It would be interesting to see the code and/or a working example.